# how can i define the injector to my app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc9/angular-1.0.0rc9.js

The above link defined external js file i don't know the injector to angular-1.0.0rc9.js so the my app is not run in browser

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['what injector:module is define here']);

please help me

Comment: i m doing infinite scroll in angular js

Comment: the data are coming from some services

Comment: can you help me for that request how can i do infinite scroll in angular js with http services

Comment: First google hit was [this](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

Comment: as tried different way but i didnt get answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to inject any dependencies to start your app. However you should add dependencies when you need them.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp');
})();
```

Let's say you need the ui.bootstrap dependency, you can modify your code to look like this.

```
(function () {
        'use strict';
         var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 })();
```

Comment: hi i using the that mentioned external js file thats y how can define in my app

Comment: how can i do infinite scroll in angular js with http services